API 4 Explorer: Adding my custom action to existing Api4 Action from Civi
I am trying to add a custom API4 action to an existing Civi API4 action.
Example:
Email entity. Add new action to do some stuff.
In Api3 it is possible. In API4, I am not sure how to do it if possible. Was trying to make a Civi/Api4/Action/Email extending \Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction but I am getting Class does not exist in Api4 Explorer.
CiviCRM Chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/z8rtpidmjtn6icouyqi1qq8u7e

I was apparently missing classloader in info.xml. Updated it and is now working.
